# Docker For Mac IP address

Tags: docker

I am running an Elasticsearch in a Docker container. To access this from an app running inside another container I can specify elasticsearch host as the machine local IP address on a Mac.

I want to bundle the es host config inside the image, to make it just work without external files, but the issue I have is the image will only work with that IP, so a different mac on the network will not be able to use the image as the es host config will not be correct.

Any ideas how I can use a single IP in the config that will work in all cases, regardless if IP changes?

Comment: Instead of specifying the local IP, why don't you link both containers and let your app access ES by hostname (elasticsearch container name)?

Comment: Havent tried this. So would the ES host be the container name?

Answer (score 2):

Linking both containers solved the issue (thanks for suggestion héctor)
By creating a custom network and adding both containers to the network, this allows them to communicate.

I then set Elasticsearch host to container name (of es container), as Docker will automatically resolve the container name to its internal IP.

- Created network e.g. docker network create mynet
- used --network mynet when running both containers & specified --name
- Specified elasticsearch host using container name e.g. es-container

Comment: Glad to help you!